# XSLT combine sorting with sum

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, sum

Let's say that I have the following XML:

```
<A name="a1">
    <x t="1">4.0</x>
    <A name="a1.1">
        <x t="1">2.0</x>
        <x t="2">3.0</x>
    </A>
    <A name="a1.2">
         <x t="1">4.0</x>
    </A>
    <A name="a1.3">
         <x t="1">4.0</x>
         <x t="2">2.0</x>
         <x t="3">5.0</x>
    </A>
</A>
```

I'm using Saxon 6.5.5 and XSLT 1.0.

Here I have a recursive structure but for the purpose of simplicity let's say that nesting is allowed only up to two levels that is a top **A** element may contain none, one or multiple other **A** elements but those sub-**A** elements cannot contain sub-sub-**A** elements and so on. Each of the sub-**A** elements contains at least on **x** element with some floating point numeric value in it. The top level **A** element has a single **x** element, which stores the average of all MAXIMUM **x** values in each sub-**A** element based on the number of sub-**A** elements. In the example above we have 3 sub-**A** elements: *a1.1* with highest value 3, *a1.2* with highest value 4 and *a1.3* with highest value 5. The top level **A** element *a1* accordingly has the value of (3+4+5)/3=4. Note also that if multiple values in a sub-**A** element are the same and are the highest (example: 2,3,4,4 -> two elements have value 4, which is also the maximum) only one is taken into account. At the end the only thing that these values are used for is to assign a maximum to the sub-**A** element they are representing.

```
<A name="a1">
    <x t="1">4.0</x>--------<---------<---------| (sum(3,4,5) div count(A))=12/3=4
    <A name="a1.1">                             |
        <x t="1">2.0</x>-----|__max(2,3)=3----->+
        <x t="2">3.0</x>-----|                  |
    </A>                                        |
    <A name="a1.2">                             |
         <x t="1">4.0</x>-----|__max(4)=4------>+
    </A>                                        |
    <A name="a1.3">                             |
         <x t="1">4.0</x>-----|                 |
         <x t="2">2.0</x>-----|--max(4,2,5)=5-->+
         <x t="3">5.0</x>-----|
    </A>
</A>
```

My problem is the extraction of the highest value inside each sub-**A** element and combining all those with the XSLT function **sum()**.

I know that

```
<xsl:for-each select="x">
    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

will sort my **x** and take here since I'm using ascending order will give me the largest numeric value.

On the other hand

```
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(A/x) div count(A)"/>
```

will return the sum of all **x** elements in each sub-**A** element. Here I didn't include the outer for-each loop for looping through each top level **A** element since it makes things more complicated so let's say for now that I'm concentrating only on the example above. In the case where each sub-**A** element contains a *single* **x** element, this will work as intended. Once I get multiple **x** elements inside some sub-**A** element it gets all screwed up.

The things I've described above should be doable and it is actually a piece of cake if XSLT was procedural and not functional language. However I have zero experience with functional programming including XSLT. :-/  If we are talking procedural code here one can simply declare a bunch of variables (one to store the current sum, one for the largest number in the current sub-**A** element and one to store the number of sub-**A** elements) and while looping through each sub-**A** element extract the maximum from each **x** element and add it to the sum so far. At the end all that remains is divide by the number of sub-**A** elements and store the value in the **x** element of the top level **A** element.

Comment: What if there are two or more `x` siblings at maximum value?

Comment: Only a single one is taken into consideration. That is why sorting and taking the last() or first() (depending on how you sort your values) is so appropriate. I'll add this to the question. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. If using XSLT 1.0, it would be useful to know which specific processor. -- P.S. I am not sure that simplifying by limiting the nesting is a good idea here; the answer might not fit your real situation.

Comment: Thanks, added the information at the beginning. As for the recursive structure - it is actually up to 2 sub-levels deep. I still haven't figured out if it's possible to limit recursion so I decided to add this minimal example with only 2 levels since it represents my situation pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use XSLT 2.0 with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9? Then you can simply write `sum(A/max(x))` to compute the sum of the maximum `x` values of the `A` element children (and then of course `sum(A/max(x)) div count(A)` to compute the average. With XSLT 1.0 you need `sum(A/x[not(. < preceding-sibling::x) and not(. < following-sibling::x)][1])` respectively for the average `sum(A/x[not(. < preceding-sibling::x) and not(. < following-sibling::x)][1]) div count(A)`. The expressions are XPath expressions, inside of XSLT attributes you need to escape the `<` as `&lt;` obviously.

A complete sample to compute the sum is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/A">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(A/x[not(. &lt; preceding-sibling::x) and not(. &lt; following-sibling::x)][1])"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which when applied with Saxon 6.5.5 to your input outputs `12`, to compute the average is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/A">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(A/x[not(. &lt; preceding-sibling::x) and not(. &lt; following-sibling::x)][1]) div count(A)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if you can use Saxon 6.5.5 with Java you can as well switch to Saxon 9.5 or 9.6 to use XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/A">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(A/max(x)) div count(A)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvV for a working sample.

Comment: Hi, I added the information to the beginning of my question. Sorry for missing that. As for your suggestion it doesn't seem to work or maybe I'm just doing it wrong. :D I still get a sum of all grades and not the maximum in each sub-**A** element. Can you please elaborate more on your solution?

Comment: Okay, I have decided to switch to XSLT 2.0 since it's a lot easier in my case to use it (not only in this case but in a couple of others) instead of writing jerky XPath expressions with v1.0. Your XSLT 2.0 solution works like a charm! Thank you so much. ^_^ Will mark your reply as the answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing concerning your solution and it should be added namely the division by the count of sub-**A** elements, which in your case is missing. Otherwise I'll just get the sum of all max grades in each sub-**A** element and not the average.

Comment: @rbaleksandar, I have edited the answer to include the division for the average computation.

Comment: Cool, now it's complete :-3 Thanks again.

Comment: A small change allows to take more control over what is passed into the sum-operation by sum(tns:A/(tns:x[. CONDITION])) div count(tns:A) with CONDITION being some sort of a logical expression that my tns:x has to fulfill in order to be used. For example (tns:x[. &lt; 4.0]) takes only the tns:x elements that are smaller than 4.0. This is really cool. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If you're using XSLT 1.0, I'd suggest you try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
extension-element-prefixes="math">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/A">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <avg-of-maxima>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(A/x[.=math:max(../x)][1]) div count(A)"/>
        </avg-of-maxima>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a **test input**:

```
<A name="a1">
   <A name="a1.1">
      <x t="1">2.0</x>
      <x t="2">3.0</x>
   </A>
   <A name="a1.2">
      <x t="1">4.0</x>
   </A>
   <A name="a1.3">
      <x t="1">4.0</x>
      <x t="2">2.0</x>
      <x t="3">5.0</x>
      <x t="4">5.0</x>
   </A>
</A>
```

the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A name="a1">
   <avg-of-maxima>4</avg-of-maxima>
   <A name="a1.1">
      <x t="1">2.0</x>
      <x t="2">3.0</x>
   </A>
   <A name="a1.2">
      <x t="1">4.0</x>
   </A>
   <A name="a1.3">
      <x t="1">4.0</x>
      <x t="2">2.0</x>
      <x t="3">5.0</x>
      <x t="4">5.0</x>
   </A>
</A>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I decided to use the XSLT 2.0 solution of @Martin since this is not the only place in my XSLT where the greater simplicity of expressions in v2.0 will improve my workflow.